# delay to connect database sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i've a sqlite file to use with my app and i follow this tutorial for using my sqlite file : [Link tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

in this database i've many coordinates and for every coordinates, i mark it on a fragment map of my activity.
when i start my application on my device (acer e330) give me this error:

```
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.frank.nuova/com.frank.nuova.Offline}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: linee: , while compiling: SELECT lat, long, via FROM linee
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: linee: , while compiling: SELECT lat, long, via FROM linee
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at com.frank.nuova.DataSource.vediCoordinate(DataSource.java:21)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at com.frank.nuova.Offline.onCreate(Offline.java:40)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-11 16:47:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(11095):    ... 11 more
```

but after a while (10 seconds) it works, so it make visible marks on map with right coordinates of my database.
Now with same code to connect database of this app i'm trying to use a spinner in which i list coordinates of my db.
but this app crash immediately with the same error of app before.
i've thought that is a problem of delay to connect on my database it is possible?

This is Activity:

```
public class Offline extends Activity {
MyOpenHelper o;
DataSource db;
LatLng pos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_offline);
    o=new MyOpenHelper(this);
    try{
        o.createDataBase();
    }catch (IOException e){
        throw new Error("Non posso creare il database");
    }
    try{
        o.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sql){
        sql.printStackTrace();
    }
    db=new DataSource(o);
    ListView l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Gps s=new Gps(getApplicationContext());
    Location adesso=s.getLocation();
    List<LatLng> vicini=db.piuvicino(adesso, db.vediCoordinate());
    ArrayAdapter<LatLng> a=new ArrayAdapter<LatLng>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,vicini);
    l.setAdapter(a);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.offline, menu);
    return true;
}


    }
```

this MyOpenHelper.java

```
public class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "";

    private static String DB_NAME = "orari";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public MyOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2){
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";         
        } else {
           DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }
        this.myContext = context; 
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();


            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);


    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

and DataSource.java

```
public class DataSource {
private MyOpenHelper oh;
private Cursor cu;
public DataSource(MyOpenHelper o){
    oh=o;
}
public List<Coordinate> vediCoordinate(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=oh.getReadableDatabase();
    String c[]=new String[]{"lat","long","via"};
    cu=db.query("linee", c, null, null, null, null, null);
    int rows=cu.getCount();
    LinkedList<Coordinate> risultato=new LinkedList<Coordinate>();
    cu.moveToFirst();
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        risultato.add(i,new Coordinate(cu.getDouble(cu.getColumnIndex("lat")),cu.getDouble(cu.getColumnIndex("long")),cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("via"))));
        cu.moveToNext();
    }
    cu.close();
    return risultato;   
}
public double distanza(Location l,LatLng m){
    double startlat=l.getLatitude();
    double startlon=l.getLongitude();
    double endlat=l.getLatitude();
    double endlon=l.getLongitude();
    float[]res=new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(startlat, startlon, endlat, endlon, res);
    return res[0];
}
public List<LatLng> piuvicino(Location l,List<Coordinate> a){
    LatLng b;
    double dist=0;
    LinkedList <LatLng> lista=new LinkedList<LatLng>();
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        b=new LatLng(a.get(i).getLatitudine(), a.get(i).getLongitudine());
        dist=distanza(l,b);
        if (dist<0.5){
            lista.add(new LatLng(a.get(i).getLatitudine(), a.get(i).getLongitudine()));
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the stack trace?  `No such table: linee`.

Comment: yes but it's not true...after 20 seconds it works, if linee doesn't exist how cans it mark coordinates on map?

Comment: Facing same issue, not sure what is an issue.